# Django Error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm writing code for a Django-based static blog, but I am coming across this similar issue across 3 or 4 different areas of my code. I figured if I can get one fixed then I can get the others fixed as well. My code of focus will be a django-command that I call `update_blog1`. Here's the traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 132, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Jaysp_000/firstSite/PROJECTone\blog_static\views.py", line 179, in archive
{'posts' : posts}
  File "C:/Users/Jaysp_000/firstSite/PROJECTone\blog_static\views.py", line 14, in render_response
return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 45, in render_to_response using=using)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 116, in render_to_string
template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 221, in render_to_string
return t.render(context_instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in render
with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 235, in bind_template
updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py", line 56, in i18n
context_extras['LANGUAGE_BIDI'] = translation.get_language_bidi()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 177, in get_language_bidi
return _trans.get_language_bidi()
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 263, in get_language_bidi
base_lang = get_language().split('-')[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 103, in get_format
cached = _format_cache[cache_key]
KeyError: ('r', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/Users/Jaysp_000/firstSite/PROJECTone\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
   File "C:/Users/Jaysp_000/firstSite/PROJECTone\blog_static\management\commands\update_blog1.py", line 78, in handle
resp = client.get(path)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 500, in get
**extra)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 303, in get
return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 379, in generic
return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 448, in request
response = self.handler(environ)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 122, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 218, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 261, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 97, in technical_500_response
html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
return t.render(c)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 209, in render
return self._render(context)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 201, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 79, in render_node
return node.render(context)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 89, in render
output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 674, in resolve
new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaultfilters.py", line 771, in date
return formats.date_format(value, arg)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 136, in date_format
return dateformat.format(value, get_format(format or 'DATE_FORMAT', use_l10n=use_l10n))
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 110, in get_format
for module in get_format_modules(lang):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 82, in get_format_modules
modules = _format_modules_cache.setdefault(lang, list(iter_format_modules(lang, settings.FORMAT_MODULE_PATH)))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 51, in iter_format_modules
if not check_for_language(lang):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 181, in check_for_language
return _trans.check_for_language(lang_code)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 472, in wrapper
result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 409, in check_for_language
if not language_code_re.search(lang_code):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here's my code for the **update_blog1**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test.client import Client

import sys, os
from optparse import make_option

from P1config.settings import STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Compile blog posts from html to markdown, and upload images to S3 Defaults to processing only new blog posts"

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
         make_option(
            '--all',
            action='store_true',
            dest='all',
            default=False,
            help='Get all blog posts, regardless of date'
        ),
     make_option(
        '--name',
        action='store',
        dest='post_name',
        default=False,
        help='Get named blog post'
        ),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        verbosity = int(options.get('verbosity'))

        client = Client()
        outdir = STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY
        posts = []
        previews = []


        if options['all']:
            if verbosity > 3:
                print ('Compiling all blog posts')
            posts = self._get_all_posts()
        elif options['post_name']:
            posts = self._get_named_posts(options['post_name'])
        else:
            if verbosity > 3:
                print ('Compiling new blog posts')
            posts = self._get_all_posts(new = True)

        if verbosity > 3:
            print ('%d posts found' % len(posts))
            print ('----------------------------')

        for post in posts:  
            if verbosity > 3:
                print ("Compiling " + post['md_name'] + " to " +     post['html_name'])
            path = reverse('blog_static.views.archive') + post['path']
            # path = '/preview/' + post['path']
            resp = client.get(path)
            if os.path.exists(outdir + post['path']) == False:
                try:
                    with open(outdir + post['path'], 'r') as f:
                        pass
                except IOError as e:
                    os.mkdir(outdir + post['path'])

            with open(outdir + post['html_name'], 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(resp.content) 

        if len(posts) > 0 and verbosity > 3:
            print ('----------------------------')

        if verbosity > 3:
            print ('Updating listings...')
            print ('----------------------------')
        path = reverse('blog_static.views.archive')
        resp = client.get(path)

        with open(STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY + 'index.html', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(resp.content) 

        if verbosity > 3:    
            print ('Done')


    def _get_all_posts(self, new = False):    
        posts = []
        for item in os.listdir(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY):
            post = self._create_post(item, new)
            if post:
                posts.append(post)
        return posts

    def _get_named_posts(self, post):
        post_list = post.split(',')
        posts = []
        for item in post_list:
            try:
                with open(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY + item, 'r') as f: 
                    post = self._create_post(item)
                    if post:
                        posts.append(post)
            except IOError as e:
                print ('\033[01;31m' + str(e) + '\033[0m', file= sys.stderr)
       return posts

    def _create_post(self, item, new = False):
        outdir = STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY
        compiled_post = {
            'md_name' : item,
            'html_name' : '',
            'path' : '',
            'html' : '',
        }
        if item.endswith('.md'):
            compiled_post['path'] = item.replace('.md', '')
            compiled_post['html_name'] = compiled_post['path'] + '/index.html'
            if new:
               try:
                    with open(STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY + compiled_post['html_name'], 'r') as f: 
                    return False
                except IOError as e:
                    return compiled_post
            else:
                return compiled_post
```

If you look in the code, the methods `_get_named_posts()`, `_create_post()`, `handle()` each have a open() function embedded. Where these open() functions are (ex: `open(outdir + post['path'], 'r'` or `open(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY + item, 'r')`) is where the problem lies, as pointed out by PyCharm.

In my `view.py file`, I got have this...

```
# Django imports
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.db import models

# Create a 'shortcut' function to wrap request in RequestContext()
def render_response(req, *args, **kwargs):
    """Shortcut to wrap request in RequestContext"""
    kwargs['context_instance'] = RequestContext(req)
    return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)

# Standard Python lib
import os, sys, urllib, hashlib

# 3rd party apps
import markdown
from markdown.inlinepatterns import ImagePattern, IMAGE_LINK_RE

# from config folder
from P1config.settings import STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY, \
                                STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, \
                                STATICBLOG_STORAGE

###################################################################################

class S3ImagePattern(ImagePattern):
    """ Wrapper class to handle image matches in markdown document """

    def handleMatch(self, match):
        node = ImagePattern.handleMatch(self, match)
        # check 'src' to ensure it is local
        src = node.attrib.get('src')
        storage_class = get_storage_class(STATICBLOG_STORAGE)
        storage = storage_class()

        # otherwise we need to do some downloading!
        if 'http://' in src or 'https://' in src:
            img_data = urllib.request.urlopen(src).read()
            md5 = hashlib.md5()
            md5.update(img_data)
            name = md5.hexdigest() + '/' + os.path.basename(src)
        else:
            with open(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY + src) as fhandle:
                img_data = fhandle.read()
            name = src

        print('Uploading ' + src, file=sys.stderr)
        try:
            storage.save(name, ContentFile(img_data))
            node.attrib['src'] = storage.url(name)
            print ('Uploaded ' + src + ' to ' + storage.url(name), file=sys.stderr)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e), file=sys.stderr)
            print ('\033[01;31mUpload of %s failed\033[0m' % src, file=sys.stderr)
        return node


def render_post(request, post_name):
    """ Render a blog post based on a .post template
    The used template is rendered as html in the folder defined
    by STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY
    """
    content = ""
    mdown = markdown.Markdown(extensions = ['meta',])
    mdown.inlinePatterns['image_link'] = S3ImagePattern(IMAGE_LINK_RE, mdown)
    try:
        post_file_dir = os.path.join(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, post_name + '.md')    
        with open(post_file_dir, 'r') as pfDIR:
            content = pfDIR.read()         # opening and reading the ENTIRE '.md' document
            html = mdown.convert(content)  # converting file from '.md' to ".html"

    except IOError as e:
        print (str(e))
        with open(os.path.join(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, 'preview2.md')) as f:
            content = f.read()
            html = mdown.convert(content)

    post = { 'content' : html, }

    try:
        post['date'] = mdown.Meta['date'][0]
        post['title'] = mdown.Meta['title'][0]
        post['author'] = mdown.Meta['author'][0]
        post['summary'] = mdown.Meta['summary'][0]
        post['tags'] = mdown.Meta['tags'][0]
    except:
        pass

    meta = {}
    if 'title' in post:
        meta['title'] = post['title']

    # Context Object containing the post, meta contexes
    context = {'post' : post, 'meta' : meta}

    return render_response(  # but could I just use render?
        request,
        'post2.html',
        context
    )


def archive(request):
    mdown = markdown.Markdown(extensions = ['meta',])
    # Create an empty post list for now
    posts = []
    import string
    # Look at every 'item' in the STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY
    for item in os.listdir(STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY):
        # if the 'item' in this directory ends with '.post' (like '.md' in a markdown file, or '.py' in a python file)
        # More specifically, if there is a '.post' file located in this directory...
        if item.endswith('.md'):
            # ...continue on and...
            continue
        # ...attempt to use that 'item'
        try:
            # ...by opening it, 
            with open(os.path.join(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, item + '.md')) as fhandle:
                # ...reading the markdown file,
                content = fhandle.read() # (opening and reading the ENTIRE '.md' document)
                # ...and converting it to HTML.
                mdown.convert(content)   # (converting file from '.md' to ".html")

                post = { 'name' : item, }
                if 'title' in mdown.Meta and len(mdown.Meta['title'][0]) > 0:
                    # Add the markdown document's 'title' to post[]
                    # This stores the post's title from the "Meta" section of the '.md' document
                    post['title'] = mdown.Meta['title'][0]
                # but if that doesnt work...
                else:
                    # Add to the post list the item's Meta 'title', which simply takes \n
                    #   the title of the .md document and removes the '-' from it, so that \n 
                    #   we can make it the post's title.
                    post['title'] = string.capwords(item.replace('-', ' '))
                # ...and if there exists a 'date' in the item's meta attribute...
                if 'date' in mdown.Meta:
                    # pass the 'date' info found in the Meta attribute to a 'date' \n
                    #   variable created in the post list
                    post['date'] = mdown.Meta['date'][0]

                posts.append(post)
        except:
            pass

    from operator import itemgetter
    posts = sorted(posts, key=itemgetter('date'))
    posts.reverse()

    return render_response(  # but could I just use render?
        request,
        'archive.html',
        {'posts' : posts}
    )   


@csrf_exempt
def handle_hook(request):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.core.management import call_command
    result = call_command('update_blog', verbosity = 0)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

I dont know how to fix this. Can you let me know how to fix these issues? I don't know where I can put a string or buffer in my code.

Comment: split() will work on string only.

Comment: Your actually error is in the first half of the traceback: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Comment: And since that error originates in `views.py`, notably in the `archive` function, you'll need to look at what happens there (or post the code for that view in your question).